# Getting started with cross-platform FileMQ over ZeroMQ

Tags: zeromq, filemq

Could anyone recommend some good resources for getting started with FileMQ and ZeroMQ in a cross-platform setting?

I'm either looking for tutorials or guides or shellscripts that somehow tell me how I tie it together. Unfortunately, despite the statements of being cross-platform, I haven't been able to make it work on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

The FileMQ project contains MSVC project files, I think. Otherwise, try emailing the zeromq-dev list and ask if anyone's done this.

Comment: Yepp, they are located here (although they may of course be broken): https://github.com/zeromq/filemq/tree/master/win32

Comment: "It doesn't work" isn't very helpful :-) Tell us at least what compiler you are using, what steps you took to try to build this, and what the first errors were.

Comment: I'm absolutely certain that you haven't tried to compile it on Windows. I get hundreds of errors. I have tried C++VS2010Express on Windows 7, VS2010Ultimate on Windows 7 and VS2012 Ultimate on Windows 8, cygwin/gcc and Clang in both Windows (PowerShell) and cygwin environments as well as its GUI; even tried generting a bunch of different buildfiles for it. It doesn't compile. Try it yourself. :)

Comment: Henrik, for various reasons I don't have a Windows box so indeed I've not tried building it on Windows. It could be missing dependencies, non-portable code, or other issues. However if you don't provide even the first few errors, it's impossible to help you.